# I am having a difficult time getting a simple React JS to start or run

Tags: reactjs

I am having a difficult time getting a simple React JS to start or run. Her are my 2 simple files and package.json.

**App.js**

```
export default App;const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**index.js**

```
import { render } from ReactDOM
import App from './App'

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "first-react-application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried start index.js and start App.js.  I don't get any errors server just won't run.  I try to connect to 127.0.0.0:3000 and localhost:3000 and my browser never connects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the ‘ export default App;’ before the const in App.js

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed something so simple.